# problem with plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am having a problem with the following code for generating a plot. I don't know why the first group (Yago) does not include the first entry (the blue one for Sys1) and the second group does not include the last entry (the green one for Sys6). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}[
                major x tick style = transparent,
            xtick=data,
                ybar,
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = 100,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            ylabel = {Offline Time (in min.)},
                xlabel = {Data Set},
                symbolic x coords = {Yago,DBLP},
                ytick = {0,20,40,60,80,100},
                scaled y ticks = false,
            bar width=10pt,
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,20) (DBLP,12)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,45) (DBLP,30)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,30) (DBLP,15)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,65) (DBLP,45)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,25) (DBLP,14)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,35) (DBLP,25)};

            \legend{Sys1,Sys2,Sys3,Sys4,Sys5,Sys6}

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting rid of the extra space. Can you please tell me how you accomplished that? I crop the picture using Acrobat, but it still shows that darn additional space. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) I used `gimp` to crop the space

Comment: @ozsu: Could you change your question title to be more descriptive? That will make it easier for others with the same problem to find the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bars are there, but there's not enough room for them to appear: you can use `enlarge x limits` and/or decrease the `bar width`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}[
                major x tick style = transparent,
            xtick=data,
                ybar,
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = 100,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            ylabel = {Offline Time (in min.)},
                xlabel = {Data Set},
                symbolic x coords = {Yago,DBLP},
                ytick = {0,20,40,60,80,100},
                scaled y ticks = false,
            bar width=6pt,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,20) (DBLP,12)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,45) (DBLP,30)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,30) (DBLP,15)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,65) (DBLP,45)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,25) (DBLP,14)};
            \addplot coordinates {(Yago,35) (DBLP,25)};

            \legend{Sys1,Sys2,Sys3,Sys4,Sys5,Sys6}

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]